# What is the es6 equivalent of node_modules?

Tags: es6-modules, es6-module-loader

I'm used to `require` but I'm playing with es6 modules. I decided to change my directory structure, which meant that I had to go and change all of the import statements (`import thing from "../thing"` became `import thing from "../../thing"` etc).

I had to go through and change a lot of this. With node_modules, this is never an issue.

Do you always have to specify a path in es6 modules or is there some sort of system/order-of-operation for finding modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent to `node_modules` in ES6, meaning no modules can be imported by name, from a pre-defined directory. No such directory exists, and so modules must be imported by path.

The practice for ES6 modules is to put them in a flat(ish) directory structure, like the one you created with all of your `../thing` changes.

BTW, bundlers virtualize this process, which is why you may not be used to seeing `import '../thing'`

If you would like to support both ES6 and Node.js style modules, as well as flat and node_modules directory structure, check out this [example](https://github.com/isysd-mirror/iso-module-boilerplate) and it's introductory [article](https://medium.com/@iravagecoins/isomorphic-es6-node-js-module-boilerplate-w-universal-testing-bb962f02670d).